# Getting error 421 4.3.2 All server ports are busy

Tags: email, postfix

I am running postfix on debian wheezy with Dovecot and I had spam issues with a php script . after finding and removing the script I am unable to send any mails from squirrel mail from my browser. I get

ERROR:
Message not sent. Server replied:
Service not available, closing channel
421 4.3.2 All server ports are busy

How can i track this issue down and What information should I provide to resolve this issue?

thanks

Comment: Please check your `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: Jan 19 13:06:54 htz postfix/postscreen[10888]: warning: cannot connect to service private/smtpd: No such file or directory
Jan 19 13:06:55 htz postfix/postscreen[10888]: PASS NEW [64.20.227.133]:62525
Jan 19 13:06:55 htz postfix/postscreen[10888]: DISCONNECT [64.20.227.133]:62525
Jan 19 13:08:35 htz postfix/postscreen[10888]: close database /var/lib/postfix/postscreen_cache.db: No such file or directory (possible Berkeley DB bug)

Comment: I guess you have already tried to restart postfix ?:)  Please share the output of `postconf -n`

Comment: I don't even have enough rep to copy the output but http://mxtoolbox.com tells me this : Connecting to 178.63.21.220

SendSMTPCommand: You hung up on us after we connected. Please whitelist us. (connection lost)

MXTB-PWS3v2 1435ms

Comment: I also get Jan 19 13:15:01 htz postfix/postscreen[11386]: warning: cannot connect to service private/smtpd: No such file or directory in my mail log

Comment: It look's like you are using `postscreen` and it could be dropping the connections. You can try to disable it temporarily.

Comment: Please check your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` for `postscreen_access_list` most probably `/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr` then try to add your client to white list,  example `192.168.0.1          permit`

Comment: I have no postscreen in the main.cf or in the postfix folder at all

Comment: Could you check if there is any infromation about postscreen in /etc/postfix/master.cf ?

Comment: smtp    inet    n       -       -       -       1       postscreen

Comment: So it looks like you have postscreen enabled but it's not configured at all, please comment out the `postscreen` line in master.cf  and uncomment `smtp inet ... smtpd` and reload/restart postfix. Please take a look at [this](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#turnoff)

Comment: I commented the postscreen line and now I am unable to open squirrelmail which is my web base email handler

Comment: You also need uncomment smtp inet ... smtpd and reload/restart postfix. Please take a look at the postscreen [manual](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#turnoff)

Comment: Thanks for your replies . Commenting both of them will leave me with : Connection refused 111 Can't open SMTP stream.

Comment: You need to coment out(remove the postscreen line) and **UN** comment(add) the smtpd line

Comment: Well That solved my issues in the sending part .. I now am able to send mail again but not able to receive .. webmin postfix says : mail transport unavailable

Comment: Please add to the question, the output of your your master.cf and the mil.log after you changes.

Comment: I've uploaded my main.cf here because I do not have enough rep to post the answer yet : http://shrib.com/dZ4wq2KD

Comment: Please also share the master.cf file. BTW is your dovecot daemon running?

Comment: http://shrib.com/z2di1fNg this is my master.cf and dovecot service is running

Comment: Hmm... you are running Dovecot as your MTA right? If so, why is there no dovecot entry in your master.cf ? How should postfix know that it has to move the emails to dovecot ? You need to add dovecot to your master.cf: something like: `dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
`Was your email ever working properly ? Take a look at this [tutorial](https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy)

Comment: I did add dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} to my master.cf and now I am able to send and receive .. I do not know how to thank you but you are an angel sent from heaven or something. great job

Comment: can you post the answer so atleast I tick it for the future if anyones having the same problem ?

Comment: Great to hear that it's working!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the data that you provided it looks like you have enabled [postscreen](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html) but it is not properly configured. The best option is to disable it for now to check if this helps. Please us this [howto](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#turnoff) to disable it. Also from the provided `master.cf` it looks like you don't have an MTA(dovecot) configured in postfix. 
Please add dovecot configuration to the `master.cf` so postfix will now that it has to move the mails to MTA. an example below(you probably will need to modifiy it a little bit)

`dovecot unix - n n - - pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail 
 argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}`

Comment: This helped a lot.  I uncommented the wrong line in my master.cf and ran postscreen instead of smtpd.